# How to find the variance of the sample mean, given the population mean, standard deviation and sample size

Tags: statistics, data-science, scipy.stats

**Problem Statement : Given a sample of size n = 60 taken from a continuous population distribution with mean 56 and standard deviation 25, find the variance of the sample mean.**

I tried the below code but as expected, there is no fixed answer. And my answer is shown incorrect.

```
dist = scipy.stats.norm(loc=56, scale=25)
sample = dist.rvs(60)
x = np.var(sample)
```

Comment: The formula is  `σ2 / N`. So the result will be `math.pow(25, 2)/60) ` i.e `10.416666666666666` .

Answer (score 1):

```py
Err = math.sqrt(25/60)
dist = scipy.stats.norm(loc=56, scale=Err)
Variance = np.variance(dist)
```

Its something around 10.52

Comment: Please add some explanation.